# How do I remove java version "1.6.0_65"?

Tags: macos, java

Every single time I try to install the Oracle Java Runtime Environment... I keep being stuck with Apple's Java 6. I have no idea how Apple's Java 6 ended up on my computer in the first place. The mac OS version is High Sierra 10.13.4.

I keep putting "java -version" into the terminal and it comes out telling me I'm still running 6...

How do I remove Java 6 completely as I need to install java 8 instead?

Comment: How and from what URL are you installing oracle java and how do you run it?

Comment: Note that JRE from Oracle does not update the command line Java - you nee the JDK for that

Answer (score 1):

Visit first this page: [How do I uninstall Java on my Mac?](https://java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml) and see that Oracle is offering a tool for uninstalling ([here](https://java.com/en/download/uninstalltool.jsp)).